# Set Authorization Headers in ApolloClient for each request

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

I am learning GraphQL and Next.js through a Udemy Course and the author uses ApolloClient from apollo-boost package. But @apollo/client package is the new one and I started using that instead.

using apollo-boost's ApolloClient the author sets the credentials for each request like below:

```
new ApolloClient({
      request: operation => {
        operation.setContext({
          fetchOptions: {
            credentials: 'include'
          },
          headers
        })
      },
      uri: process.env.BASE_URL,
      cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || {})
})
```

This is not working for me as request is not present in @apollo/client's ApolloClient. So I tried like below:

```
const link = new HttpLink({ uri: "http://localhost:3000/graphql", credentials: 'include' });
new ApolloClient({
      cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || { }),
      link,
    })
```

But the credentials are not working for each request. I am not getting user information.
I am using passport which is storing logged in user info in cookies.
Below is the index.js file for configuring passport:

```
const config = require('../config/dev');
const sessison = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
exports.init = (server, db) => {
  require('./passport').init(passport);
  const sess = {
    name: 'portfolio-session',
    secret: config.SESSION_SECRET,
    cookie: { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 100},
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: db.initSessionStore()
  }

  server.use(sessison(sess));
  server.use(passport.initialize());
  server.use(passport.session());
}
```

Can somebody help with code to add authentication to ApolloClient?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it you are not actually passing the header bearing the token in your example.
Take the headers incoming from the first author's example:

```
[...]
   fetchOptions: {
            credentials: 'include'
          },
          headers // <- this one
        })
      },
[...]
```

Add it to the request like you were trying to do:

```
const link = new HttpLink({ 
  uri: "http://localhost:3000/graphql", 
  headers // <-- pass it here, should contain something along these lines: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } or w/e
});
const client = new ApolloClient({
   cache: new InMemoryCache().restore(initialState || { }),
   link,
});
```

Comment: Hi @Nemoverflow Thanks after adding the headers in the link it works.